# Zoom with Digital Crown on image (iOS 8.3)

Tags: objective-c, swift, apple-watch

Is there a way to use the Apple Watch's Digital Crown to zoom into an image, and have the user scroll with their finger? (similar to the navigation found in the Maps app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WatchKit in iOS 8.2, iOS 8.3, Xcode 6.2 and 6.3 the api for the Digital Crown is not available.